# how to support big size content in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Often I have to create csv export files from the db in my apps. When I have to create 15 mbytes export  files I have problems with mvc, because to use the **return Content();** , I need to create in memory big strings with all the data, with frequent memory exception, so I have to use .aspx pages where I can user Response.Write while I'm processing the data.

The second problem trying to use mvc is that if I have to do long processing, the client see nothing come until I haven't completed the elaboration and starting to send it, and often thinks that is having connection or server problem.

Is it possible to send data to content during the processing of the action in mvc, without to end the completing of the processing?

Comment: You can use `Response.Write` in MVC too

Comment: You can make your report generation asynchronous and notify the user after it was finished (send him an email or display a url where he can download the file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a piece of code that will address this issue. Note though that you can use Web API and just create a CSV formatter (and disable output buffering) or use pushtreamcontent directly.

For MVC here is a sample code, note this sample is using a closure, but you can just the same use an IEnumerable. The key is to make the evaluation lazy, so you don't create the whole string in memory.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace SampleApplication
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult LargeCsv()
        {
            // TODO: Replace the func with real data access, or alternatively use an IQueryable/IEnumerable/IEnumerator implementation 
            // to access the data dynamically.
            int i = 0;
            Func<string> func = () =>
            {
                while (i < 100)
                {
                    i++;
                    return "Name" + i + ", " + i;
                }

                return null;
            };

            return new CsvActionResult(func);
        }
    }

    public class CsvActionResult : ActionResult
    {
        private readonly Func<string> _getNextCsvLine;

        public CsvActionResult(Func<string> getNextCsvLine)
        {
            _getNextCsvLine = getNextCsvLine;
        }

        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/csv");

            context.HttpContext.Response.BufferOutput = false;

            // StreamWriter has inherent buffering so this operation is reasonably performant, it 
            // is going to write buffers to the wire rather than each writeline.
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(context.HttpContext.Response.OutputStream))
            {
                string csvLine;

                do
                {
                    csvLine = _getNextCsvLine();
                    sw.WriteLine(csvLine);

                } while (csvLine != null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem with your application logic. I mean look into [state machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) to make your application to get into different states. So when processing the data happens, spawn a task running and will notify when a specific task is finished.

You can use JS to ask from time to time the state on the server and only when the task is finished, you can send it.

Also, make sure you [use compression](http://icsharpcode.github.io/SharpZipLib/) at the end when you send big data of results (and this may help your memory consumption also).